# How to move a div's border "up" one pixel with css

Tags: css

I have a div, which I have given a border on top. The border needs to be shifted one pixel higher. Is this possible with CSS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a negative top margin

```
{ margin-top: -1px; }
```

very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/zW6yD/

Comment: I know that negative margins give you some trouble in IE. Are there other alternatives for moving a border line up?

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
div { position: relative; margin-top: -1px; }
```